# Connected other iPhone to MB to backup...could my old photos have transferred to the phone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, apple-id, photos.app

A bit of an unusual question maybe.

A friend needed to set up her new iPhone but doesn't have a computer and is restricted to mobile data at the moment. She wanted to back up her old iPhone to use on the new one. I tried to back her old one up using an old MacBook that I thought I had wiped, but realised partway through that all my photos (from iPhoto) were still on the MB.

I had logged out of iTunes and it is logged in using my friend's Apple/iTunes account...it's just that the MB had been linked to my Apple account for my photos.

The more I think about it, the less likely it is that the photos were transferred from my MB iPhoto to her iPhone backup...but I just thought I'd check.

Is it possible or likely that they have been? I asked her if there are any photos that aren't hers and she quickly looked at the last few days and said there weren't (but the last photo on that computer was maybe 6mth/1yr ago though)...and I don't want her to think I don't believe her by asking again if it's not really possible for them to transfer that way (or between accounts...even though the iPhoto wasn't really an account?).

Is there a way to check other than getting her to scroll back up to 6mth/1yr ago and her checking through her photos?

Thanks :)

Comment: What steps did you take when setting up your friend's new iPhone? Did you set it up as a new iPhone or did you restore from the backup (of your friend's old phone that you took beforehand?).

Comment: I didn’t get to setting up the new iPhone. I had only backed up the old one. Plugged in old, backup, transferred her purchases to my computer and authorised it. It’s my old computer, so I’m planning on properly wiping it before I sell it. I don’t have iCloud activated on my photos on the old computer (if that makes a difference).

Comment: I was thinking about removing the photos from iPhoto then recreating another backup. Depending on how long it takes to wipe a laptop, I may do that as well. She’s coming back so I can finish the backup transfer today.